# Expected run in a run test.

Tags: probability, statistics

The [run test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) is used to know whether the given data is random or not. 
How can we derive the formula for the expected run with $n_1$ ups and $n_2$ downs.

Comment: Guess: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AWald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test#Derive_expected_value

Comment: yes but explicitly I m not able to derive.

Comment: "okay, I found a derivation in a textbook (Brunk 1975, Introduction to Mathematical Statistics"

Comment: @BCLC soft copy ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_{1}$ and $n_{0}$ be positive value and negative value, respectively.
Thus the length of sequence is $n = n_{0} + n_{1}$.
The number of runs is denoted by $R = R(n_{0}, n_{1})$.

Now we prove that $$\mathbb{E}[R] = \frac{2n_{0}n_{1}}{n_{0} + n_{1}} + 1$$
Let $R_{0}(n_{0}, n_{1})$, $R_{1}(n_{0}, n_{1})$ be the number of runs in a sequence ending with the negative value and the positive value respectively.

We have
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1})] 
&= \frac{n_{0}}{n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R_{0}(n_{0}, n_{1})] + \frac{n_{1}}{n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R_{1}(n_{0}, n_{1})] \\
\end{aligned}$$
In addition,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[R_{0}(n_{0}, n_{1})] 
& = \frac{n_{0} - 1}{n - 1} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R_{0}(n_{0} - 1, n_{1})] + \frac{n_{1}}{n - 1} \cdot (\mathbb{E}[R_{1}(n_{0} - 1, n_{1})] + 1) \\
& = \mathbb{E}[R(n_{0} - 1, n_{1})] + \frac{n_{1}}{n - 1} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[R_{1}(n_{0}, n_{1})] 
& = \frac{n_{1} - 1}{n - 1} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R_{1}(n_{0}, n_{1} - 1)] + \frac{n_{0}}{n - 1} \cdot (\mathbb{E}[R_{0}(n_{0}, n_{1} - 1)] + 1) \\
& = \mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1} - 1)] + \frac{n_{0}}{n - 1} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus we derive recurrence formula,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1})] 
& = \frac{n_{0}}{n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R_{0}(n_{0}, n_{1})] + \frac{n_{1}}{n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R_{1}(n_{0}, n_{1})] \\
& = \frac{n_{0}}{n} \cdot \left(\mathbb{E}[R(n_{0} - 1, n_{1})] + \frac{n_{1}}{n - 1}\right) + \frac{n_{1}}{n} \cdot \left(\mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1} - 1)] + \frac{n_{0}}{n - 1} \right) \\
& = \frac{n_{0}}{n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R(n_{0} - 1, n_{1})] + \frac{n_{1}}{n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1} - 1)] + \frac{2n_{0}n_{1}}{n(n - 1)} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Since $R_{0}(n_{0}, 0) = R_{0}(0, n_{1}) = R_{1}(n_{0}, 0) = R_{1}(0, n_{1}) = 1$, by the mathematical induction, one can easily find that
$$\mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1})] = \frac{2n_{0}n_{1}}{n} + 1$$

---

Now we can also obtain the probability distribution directly.

**Case 1:** If $R = 2k$, there are $k$ many runs of positive values and $k$ many runs of negative values.
Thus we will insert $k-1$ (resp. $k-1$) dividers into $n_{1}-1$ (resp. $n_{0}- 1$) spaces between the positive values (resp. negative values) with no more than one divider per space.
Besides there are two ways of putting the two sets of runs together.
It follows that
$$\Pr[R(n_{0},n_{1}) = 2k] 
= \frac{2\binom{n_{0}-1}{k-1}\binom{n_{1}-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{n_{0}}}$$

**Case 2:** Similarly, for $R = 2k + 1$, we have
$$\Pr[R(n_{0},n_{1}) = 2k+1] 
= \frac{\binom{n_{0}-1}{k}\binom{n_{1}-1}{k-1}+\binom{n_{0}-1}{k-1}\binom{n_{1}-1}{k}}{\binom{n}{n_{0}}}$$

Finally, we calculate the expected number of the runs.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(R(n_{0},n_{1})) 
= \sum 2k \Pr[R(n_{0},n_{1}) = 2k] + \sum (2k+1) \Pr[R(n_{0},n_{1}) = 2k+1]  
\end{equation}

For the first part,
$$\sum 2k \Pr[R(n_{0},n_{1}) = 2k] = \frac{n_{0}!n_{1}!}{n!} \cdot \frac{4(n_{0}n_{1}-1)(n-3)!}{(n_{0}-1)!(n_{1}-1)!} = \frac{4n_{0}n_{1}(n_{0}n_{1}-1)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$$
For the second part,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum (2k+1) \Pr[R(n_{0},n_{1}) = 2k+1] \\
= &\frac{n_{0}!n_{1}!}{n!} \cdot \left( \frac{(2n_{0}n_{1}-n_{1}+n_{0}-2)(n-3)!}{(n_{0}-2)!n_{1}!} + \frac{(2n_{0}n_{1}-n_{0}+n_{1}-2)(n-3)!}{n_{0}!(n_{1}-2)!} \right) \\
= &\frac{n_{0}(n_{0}-1)(2n_{0}n_{1}-n_{1}+n_{0}-2)+n_{1}(n_{1}-1)(2n_{0}n_{1}-n_{0}+n_{1}-2)}{n(n-1)(n-2)} \\
\end{aligned}$$

After some simple algebraic manipulations we finally get:
$$\mathbb{E}[R(n_{0}, n_{1})] = \frac{2n_{0}n_{1}}{n} + 1$$

---

By the way, we can also get the variance of $R$.
Similarly, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(R^{2}(n_{0}, n_{1})) = \frac{4n_{0}^{2}n_{1}^{2} + 4n_{0}^{2}n_{1} + 4n_{0}n_{1}^{2} - 4n_{0}n_{1} + n_{0}^{2} + n_{1}^2{2} - n_{0} - n_{1}}{n(n - 1)}$$

Thus
$$\mathrm{Var}(R(n_{0}, n_{1})) = \mathbb{E}(R^{2}(n_{0}, n_{1})) - \mathbb{E}(R(n_{0}, n_{1}))^{2} = \frac{2n_{0}n_{1}(2n_{0}n_{1} - n)}{n^{2}(n-1)}$$